# How to add two (or more) tableViewCells together to make a 'total'

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView that has the price and quantity of an item in the cell, and I want to add these together so if there is multiple items - it will then say the total.

This is in my `cellForRowAt`

```
detailCell.priceCostLabel.text = sortedPriceDictionary[indexPath.row]
detailCell.quantityLabel.text = String(sortedQuantityDictionary[indexPath.row])

let totalPrice = (Double(sortedPriceDictionary[indexPath.row])! * Double(sortedQuantityDictionary[indexPath.row]))
print("The total price is \(totalPrice)")
```

This is working as far as it is printing the correct price for each product and how many of each there are, but if there are 2 or 3 cells, it is printing (for example)

```
The total price is 3.9
The total price is 20.7
```

Would I create an array of totalPrice(s) and do arrayOfPrices[0] + arrayOfPrices[1]? Then again how would I know how many cells I need to add together? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you describe does not belong in cellForRowAt. That function gets called for every cell in your table view. It seems to me that what you want is to set up a section footer cell and in that cell show the sum of the price values for all the items in that section.

Comment: I want the total price to be in a label on the view (because the tableView only takes up 1/2 of the view) so all I want is the total price, which I can add to a label, not a cell at the bottom if that makes sense?

Comment: Ok, so why are you doing anything with the table view at all? Write code in your viewDidAppear that loops through your data model, adds up the prices, and displays the total into the view.

Comment: Because there are different products, quantities, and prices which are being displayed in the tableView, all in different cells because they're different and I want the total price of all cells combined

Comment: That makes no sense.

Comment: each cell has a different product, each product has a different price. So it needs to be in a table view so the user can see each product and the price of each product.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is a bit unusual.  In the world of Model-View-Controller, I would expect that the list of prices that you are trying to add up would be the Model.  If you were to do any calculations on those prices then you would do it as part of the model.  The model would know how many prices it has stored and would know how to add them up.

The TableView would just be a means of putting the values from the model on the screen.  You would create as many tableViewCells as your model demands and all the "View" part of the MVC triad would do is show them, you wouldn't actually perform calculations on the values in those cells, they're just for display.

I recommend that you read more about the MVC pattern and gain a better understanding of the role of a TableView.  You can start with Apple's description:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html

When you click on that link it will tell you that that documentation page is deprecated.  That's OK.  Read it anyway.  A Google search of MVC or Model View Controller will provide a rich collection links to help you understand the pattern, and hopefully your problem and solution.